# Seperate list into sublists of varying lengths

Tags: python

I want to separate a list into sublists, where the length of each sublist depends on the number of consecutive elements in the original list which are equal to each other. For example, [2,2,2,0,0] becomes [[2,2,2],[0,0]]. This is for python.

I think you can use list comprehension, but I'm pretty stuck.

Comment: (create list instead of print being `[list(group) for key, group in itertools.groupby(l)]`.)